# Append index number to duplicated string value in a list - by using Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a `IList<string>()` which holds  some string values, and there could be duplicated items in the list. What I want is to append a index number to end of the string to eliminate the duplication.

For example, I have these values in my list: StringA, StringB, StringC, StringA, StringA, StringB. And I  want the result looks like: StringA1, StringB1, StringC, StringA2, StringA3, StringB2. I need to retain the original order in list.

Is there a way I can just use one Lambda expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
yourList.GroupBy(x => x)
        .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x,idx) => g.Count() == 1 ? x : x + idx))
        .ToList();
```

**Edit:** If the element order matters, here is another solution:

```
var counts = yourList.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

var values = counts.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => 0);

var list = yourList.Select(x => counts[x] > 1 ? x + ++values[x] : x).ToList();
```

Comment: Note that `StringC` should have no postfix added as it's already unique.

Comment: Now you don't have `StringA1` I suggest: `.SelectMany(g => g.Select((x,idx) => g.Count() == 1 ? x : x + idx)`

Comment: It still changes the order of the list.

Comment: why would order matters?

Comment: @Selman22, thanks for the solution. I have modified the question, I prefer to retain the order.

Comment: @hardywang okey, I have update the answer according to requirements.

Comment: I like your solution very much!

Comment: This is **wrong**, You are using Dictionary , and you can't preserve order using dictionaries. "The order in which the items are returned is undefined." : (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @CriketerOnSO did you notice the actual purpose of using Dictionary here?

Comment: @CriketerOnSO, Dictionary here is only used for look up of value and count, It isn't doing anything with the order, The original List is iterated which would return the elements in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

This uses some lambda expressions and linq to do it, maintaining the order but I'd suggested a function with a `foreach` loop and `yield return` would be better.

```
var result = list.Aggregate(
        new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(),
        (cache, s) =>
        {
            var last = cache.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == s);
            if (last == null)
            {
                cache.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(s, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                if (last.Value = 0)
                {
                    last.Value = 1;
                }

                cache.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(s, last.Value + 1));
            }

            return cache;
        },
        cache => cache.Select(p => p.Value == 0 ? 
            p.Key :
            p.Key + p.Value.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "StringA", "StringB", "StringC", "StringA", "StringA", "StringB" };
var newList =
    list.Select((r, i) => new { Value = r, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(r => r.Value)
    .Select(grp => grp.Count() > 1 ?
                grp.Select((subItem, i) => new
                {
                    Value = subItem.Value + (i + 1),
                    OriginalIndex = subItem.Index
                })
                : grp.Select(subItem => new
                {
                    Value = subItem.Value,
                    OriginalIndex = subItem.Index
                }))
    .SelectMany(r => r)
    .OrderBy(r => r.OriginalIndex)
    .Select(r => r.Value)
    .ToList();
```

and you will get:

```
StringA1,StringB1,StringC,StringA2,StringA3,StringB2
```

If you don't want to preserve order then you can do:

```
var newList = list.GroupBy(r => r)
                .Select(grp => grp.Count() > 1 ? 
                           grp.Select((subItem, i) => subItem + (i + 1))
                           : grp.Select(subItem => subItem))
                .SelectMany(r => r)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: It looks like the order is still changed, all "A" values are before "B" values before "C" value.

Comment: @hardywang, check the edited version, first snippet should keep the original order in place.